# what is the largest $\delta >0$ which fits the definition of continuity of the function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Given $\epsilon >0$, what is the largest $\delta >0$ which fits the definition of continuity of the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{x+3}{2},& \text{if } x \leq 1\\
    \frac{7-x}{3}, &\text{if } x\geq 1\\
    \end{cases}$$

at $x=1.$

I try to find out $\vert f(x)-f(1)\vert < \epsilon$ for two different cases but I get nothing. Please help.

Comment: have you tried to do a sketch? What is epsilon and the maximal delta in your sketch. I think this gives you the right idea

Answer (score 2):

For $x<1$: $|f(x)-f(1)|=|\frac{x+3}{2}-2|=\frac{1}{2}|x-1|$

and

for $x<1$: $|f(x)-f(1)|=|\frac{7-x}{3}-2|=\frac{1}{3}|x-1|$.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: I do that part.........

Comment: so when $\vert x -1 \vert< \delta$ then $f(x)-f(1)<\delta/2$ and $<\delta/3$

Comment: Then how I find $\delta$?

Comment: please help on finding $\delta$

Comment: If $\epsilon>0$ is given, then we are very happy if $\frac{1}{2}|x-1| < \epsilon$ and $\frac{1}{3}|x-1| < \epsilon$. Thus, if $ \delta=2 \epsilon$, then $|f(x)-f(1)| < \epsilon$ for all(!) $x$ with $|x-1|< \delta$.